# Why the passed score is not storing in SCORM Cloud for SCORM 2004 3rd edition?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I launched the SCORM 2004(3rd edition) package in SCORM Cloud. I passed the exam of 80%, but the results are not stored. I attached the Sandbox Registration State results.

```
Satisfied: true
**Completed: unknown**
Progress Status: true
Attempts: 1
Suspended: true
Activity Objective #1
    Id:
    Measure Status: false
    **Normalized Measure: unknown**
    Progress Measure: true
    Satisfied Status: true
Runtime Data
    **cmi.completion_status: unknown**
    cmi.credit: Credit
    cmi.entry: Resume
    cmi.exit: Suspend
    cmi.learner_preference
        cmi.learner_preference.audio_level: 1
        cmi.learner_preference.language:
        cmi.learner_preference.delivery_speed: 1
        cmi.learner_preference.audio_captioning: 0
    **cmi.location: 2_8
    cmi.mode: Normal
    cmi.progress_measure:
    cmi.score_scaled:
    cmi.score_raw: 80**
    cmi.score_min:
    cmi.score_max:
    **cmi.total_time: 0000:00:28**
    Total Time Tracked by SCORM Engine: 0000:00:29.12
    cmi.success_status: Passed
    cmi.suspend_data:
    Static Data
        cmi.completion_threshold:
        cmi.launch_data:
        cmi.learner_id: test@domain.com
        cmi.learner_name: Test Test
        cmi.max_time_allowed:
        cmi.scaled_passing_score:
        cmi.time_limit_action: Undefined
```

When I tried with the same course in SCORM 1.2 version, I can see all the results in SCORM cloud. I don't know, what is the issue on this.

Here, I attached the script also,

```
function getResults(correct_count, answers_key, total, grade) {
        var form_result = $('form').serializeArray();
        $.each(form_result, function(i, val) {
            if(answers_key[i] == val.value) {
                correct_count += 1; 
            }
        });
        var score = Math.round(parseFloat(parseFloat(correct_count, 10) * 100)/ parseFloat(total, 10));

        setScore(score);
        if(score >= grade) {
            setPassFail('passed');
        } else {
            setPassFail('failed');
        }
    }


    function setPassFail(sPassFail) {
        /* see if this SCORM 2004 */
        if (_sAPI == "API_1484_11") {
            /* it is SCORM 2004, set the success status */
            scormSetValue("cmi.success_status", sPassFail+"");
        } else if (_sAPI == "API") {
            /* it is SCORM 1.2,set the completion status */
            scormSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", sPassFail+"");
        }
    }

    function setScore(sScore) {     /* see if this SCORM 2004 */    if (_sAPI == "API_1484_11") {       /* it is SCORM 2004, set the scaled score data */ //        scormSetValue("cmi.score.scaled", sScore+"");       scormSetValue("cmi.score.raw", sScore+"");      scormCommit();  } else if (_sAPI == "API") {        /* it is SCORM 1.2, set the min and max scores
*/      scormSetValue("cmi.core.score.raw", sScore+"");     } }
    function scormSetValue(name, value) {
        var API = getAPI();
        if (API == null)
            return "true";

        /* call the correct SCORM function */
        if (_sAPI == "API")
            var result = API.LMSSetValue(name, value);
        else
            var result = API.SetValue(name, value);
        return result;
    } 

function scormCommit() {
    var API = getAPI();
    if (API == null)
        return "false";

    /* call the correct SCORM function */
    if (_sAPI == "API")
        var result = API.LMSCommit("");
    else
        var result = API.Commit("");
    return result;
}
```

Please help me, what is the mistake/issue is there in the code.

Thanks!

Hi,
I made all the changes and got the results in SCORM Cloud. But I didn't get the Overall Score for the course. Is there any thing i want to add?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the fix for the issues as per your guidance and did some R&D myself with code.

**1) Updated few namespace and its values:**
using the namesapce "completion_status" instead of "success_status" in all the places.

Ex:

```
function setPassFail(sPassFail) {
    /* see if this SCORM 2004 */
    if (_sAPI == "API_1484_11") {
        /* it is SCORM 2004, set the success status */
//      scormSetValue("cmi.success_status", sPassFail+"");
        scormSetValue("cmi.completion_status", sPassFail+"");
    } else if (_sAPI == "API") {
        /* it is SCORM 1.2,set the completion status */
        scormSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", sPassFail+"");
    }
}
```

**2) Added supporting namespaces:** calculated the percentage values from the Score and passed it in "cmi.score.scaled" namespace and additionally added "cmi.score.raw" namespace as per your guidance.

```
function setScore(sScore) {
    /* see if this SCORM 2004 */
    if (_sAPI == "API_1484_11") {
        /* it is SCORM 2004, set the scaled score data */
//      scormSetValue("cmi.score.scaled", sScore+"");
        var scaled_score = (sScore / 100);
        scormSetValue("cmi.score.scaled", scaled_score+"");
        scormSetValue("cmi.score.raw", sScore+"");
        scormCommit();
    } else if (_sAPI == "API") {
        /* it is SCORM 1.2, set the min and max scores */
        scormSetValue("cmi.core.score.raw", sScore+"");
    }
}
```

**3) Finally, added the score.min and score.max values and calculated the grede:**

```
function getResults(correct_count, answers_key, total, grade) {
        var form_result = $('form').serializeArray();
        $.each(form_result, function(i, val) {
            if(answers_key[i] == val.value) {
                correct_count += 1; 
            }
        });
        var score = Math.round(parseFloat(parseFloat(correct_count, 10) * 100)/ parseFloat(total, 10));

        setScore(score);
        scormSetValue("cmi.score.min", "0");
        scormSetValue("cmi.score.max", "100");

        if(score >= grade) {
          //setPassFail('passed');
            var sPassFail = 'passed';
            scormSetValue("cmi.completion_status", sPassFail+"");
            scormSetValue("cmi.success_status", sPassFail+"");
            setPassFail('completed');
        } else {
            //setPassFail('failed');
            var sPassFail = 'passed';
            scormSetValue("cmi.completion_status", sPassFail+"");
            scormSetValue("cmi.success_status", sPassFail+"");
            setPassFail('incomplete');
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help, friends!

Answer (score 2):

In order to save data set against the API you must invoke `API.Commit('')` or `API.LMSCommit('')` in order to save the student attempt data.

I would start there. Committing the data can be accomplished thru a navigational button like a save button, but you can also do it right before you terminate the SCO.  Some even do it on page turns or like a auto-save every 2 minutes.

Comment: I added the API.Commit('') after the setScroe. But, I couldn't get the results data. What I missed it? Is there any other changes to do it?

Comment: I have a bookmarklet too, that may aid in your fetching the current runtime status of your SCO on the LMS.  It may also pick up some LMS shenanigans if something is going on you don't know about.  https://www.cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM/.  That will at least give you a glimpse of what SCORM version is running, or if there is more than one SCORM version running at the same time (this actually happens in the wild).  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mark!

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer with `API.Commit()` is important, is the SCORM 2004 version missing the commit statements?

Also, your 1.2 code uses `cmi.score.score.raw` while your 2004 code uses `cmi.score.scaled`. `scaled` is not necessarily a drop-in replacement for `raw`, I suggest sticking with `cmi.score.raw` in SCORM 2004 unless you truly understand what goes into using `cmi.score.scaled`. (`cmi.progress_measure`, the impact your manifest can have on `cmi.score.scaled`, etc.)

Comment: I updated the cmi.score.scaled into cmi.score.raw with API.Commit(), But I am getting "Completed: unknown". I edited the post with recent changes which you mentioned. What will do the next for the fix?

Comment: There are many things that could be affecting your course. It's hard to tell from this snippet. For example, you might have settings in your manifest that override data sent from the SCO. I note your log is missing values for score.min and score.max. You need to set these when you launch the course -- if score.raw is 80 but min and max are undefined, how does the LMS know 80 means 80%?

Comment: Phil's totally right.  If you set for example a completion threshold or scaled passing score the LMS can also assume control of setting pass/fail and or completed or incomplete.   Also, if you want to set completed / incomplete you'll need to set that for SCORM 2004 using the `cmi.completion_status` to incomplete when it first starts.  Then set it to `completed` or `incomplete`.  This is normally based on progress vs score.  And SCORM 1.2 only has `cmi.core.lesson_status` so you can't break it up.

Comment: I made all the changes as per your recommendations. In Scorm Cloud, I can see the values of Completion: Complete, Success: passed, Score: unknown and Total TIme: 12m 37s in "SCORM Test Track Sandbox".  Is there any other way to get this overall score?

Comment: Again, without seeing your code and manifest, there's no way to fully troubleshoot. I suggest changing your manifest to be as barebones as possible to ensure it is not impacting your scoring. BTW SCORM Cloud provides links for logs if you want to share